# Conjecture: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^m=S_3(n)\times\frac{P_{m-3}(n)}{N_m}$ for odd $m>1 \ ;\ =S_2(n)\times\frac{P_{m-2}'(n)}{N_m}$ for even $m$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, conjectures

When I was in high school, I was fascinated by $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ so I tried to find the general solution for   $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m$ s.t $m \in \mathbb{N}$. I used a similar approach to
my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4827900/1132763)

> My approach was turning $n^m$ to $n(n-1)(n-2)\dots (n-m+1)+ f(n)$ and to use the fact that $$\displaystyle\dbinom{n}{k}+\dbinom{n}{k+1}= \dbinom{n+1}{k+1}$$  $f(n) $ will be combination of sums $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^i$ st $i<m$ which I evaluated before

I was able to to find the sum up to $m=6$.  Here, I tried to search for a pattern to find the general solution of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m $ s.t $m \in \mathbb{N}$ which I failed to do, but I noticed this pattern:
$\\[3pt]$
$$S_1(n):={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$$

$$S_2(n):={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2= \color{blue}{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}}}$$

$$S_3(n):={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^3= \color{red}{\frac{\color{red}{n^2(n+1)^2}}{\color{red}{4}}}}$$

$$S_4(n):={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^4=\color{blue}{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}} \times \frac{3n^2+3n-1}{  5}}$$

$$S_5(n):={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^5= \color{red}{\frac{\color{red}{n^2(n+1)^2}}{\color{red}{4}}} \times\frac{2n^2+2n-1}{ 3}}$$

$$S_6(n):={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^6= \color{blue}{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}} \times \frac{3n^4+6n^3-3n+1}{ 7 }}$$

$$S_7(n):={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^7= \color{red}{\frac{\color{red}{n^2(n+1)^2}}{\color{red}{4}} }\times\frac{3n^4+6n^3-n^2-4n+2}{ 6}}$$

$$S_8(n):={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^8= \color{blue}{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}} \times \frac{5n^6+15n^5+5n^4-15n^3-n^2+9n+3}{ 15}}$$

$$S_9(n):={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^9= \color{red}{\frac{\color{red}{n^2(n+1)^2}}{\color{red}{4}}} \times\frac{(n^2+n-1)(2n^4 +4n^3-n^3-3n^2+3)}{ 5}}$$

$$S_{10}(n):={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{10}= \color{blue}{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}} \times \frac{ 3 n^8+ 12 n^7+ 8 n^6 - 18 n^5- 10 n^4+ 24 n^3   + 2 n^2 - 15 n +5}{ 11}}$$

$$S_{11}(n):={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{11}= \color{red}{\frac{\color{red}{n^2(n+1)^2}}{\color{red}{4}}} \times\frac{2n^8 +8n^7+4n^6-16n^5-5n^4+26n^3-3n^2-20n+10}{ 6}}$$

$\\[6pt]$

---

I noticed that:

For odd $m>1$, $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m= \color{red}{\frac{{n^2(n+1)^2}}{{4}}} \times \frac{P_{m-3}(n)}{N_m}$ s.t $P_{m-3}(n)$ is an $m-3$ polynomial with integer coefficients $ \{a_{m-3},\dots a_1,a_0 \}$ such that $\gcd \{ a_{m-3},\dots a_1,a_0 \}=1$, $N_m\in \mathbb {N}$.

For even $m$, $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m= \color{blue}{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}}\times \frac{P_{m-2}'(n)}{N_m}$ s.t $P_{m-2}'(n)$ is an $m-2$ polynomial with integer coefficients $\{ a_{m-2},\dots a_1,a_0 \}$ such that $\gcd \{ a_{m-2},\dots a_1,a_0 \}=1$, $N_m\in \mathbb {N}$.

When I was in high school I couldn't prove this pattern, and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/sum-of-first-n-squares-equals-fracnn12n16?noredirect=1&lq=1) question reminded me of this observation that I had totally forgotten about. Now, after two years from my first attempt, I tried to prove this pattern again, but I couldn't.

---

### **EDIT**

This question has been partly answered in [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444681/maybe-faulhaber-polynomial-s-kx-0-have-only-rational-roots-0-frac12)  (The answer shows that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m$ is divisible by ${n^2(n+1)^2}$ for odd $m>1$ and
$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m$ is divisible by ${n(2n+1)(n+1)}$ for even $m$) the only missing part is to show that the denominator is a multiple of $4$ if $m\in 2\mathbb{N}+1$, and the denominator is a multiple of   $6$  if $m \in 2\mathbb{N}$.

Although this question has been almost solved before, I still would like to see if there is any other proofs or methods.

---

Update: I asked this question on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460987/is-sum-limits-k-1nki-s-3n-times-fracp-i-3nn-i-for-odd-i1-sum?noredirect=1#comment1195694_460987)

Comment: The second observation is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Faulhaber_polynomials).

Comment: Search for Faulhaber's formula.

Comment: The pattern also includes the denominators of $\,S_1\,$ and $\,S_2.\,$ below. The pattern continued in a spreadsheet I used with Pascal's triangle and Cramer's rule to $\,S_{31}.$
\begin{align*}
S_1=\sum_{x=1}^n x^1
&= \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\\
S_2=\sum_{x=1}^n x^2
&=S_1\dfrac{(n+2)}{3}\\
S_3=\sum_{x=1}^n x^3
&= S_1^2\\
S_4=\sum_{x=1}^n x^4
&=S_2\dfrac{(3n^2+3n-1)}{5}\\
S_5=\sum_{x=1}^n x^5
&=S_1^2\dfrac{(2n^2+2n-1)}{3}\\
S_6=\sum_{x=1}^n x^6
&=S_2\dfrac{(3n^4+6n^3-3n+1)}{7}\\
S_7=\sum_{x=1}^n x^7
&=S_1^2\dfrac{(3n^4+6n^3-n^2-4n+2)}{6}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: @poetasis do you have a proof ?

Comment: @pie I'm sorry I do not have proof. I only found that the pattern continues at east thru $\,S_{31}$.

Comment: Your sum for $S_4$ is incorrect. The term should probably be $(3n^2 + 3n)$

Comment: @sku  why     ?I checked this formula from wolfram

Comment: check for $n = 2$. It should be $(3n^2 + 3n - 1)$ perhaps

Comment: @sku you are right it should be $3n^2+3n-1$ it was a typo

Comment: This is equivalent to the claim that the Faulhaber polynomials (your sums up to $n$) have roots including $\{0,-1/2,-1\}$ at even powers $i$ and roots including $\{0,-1\}$ at odd powers $i$. This has been noted on a few pages, for instance [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444681/maybe-faulhaber-polynomial-s-kx-0-have-only-rational-roots-0-frac12). To prove it, I'd suggest using the Faulhaber polynomials' generating function or by induction.

Comment: See also, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427695/zeros-of-faulhabers-formula).

Comment: @Jam Thank you very much

Comment: @Jam I want to learn more about Faulhaber polynomials and Bernoulli numbers, what books should I use ?

Comment: @sku  There are sum formulas [here](https://polysum.tripod.com/) I think you should look at.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272004/find-p-frac12-given-a-infinite-points-of-a-polynomial/4279547#4279547)

Comment: Re your EDIT: the integer dominators $4$ and $6$ are not missing parts as they do not affect polynomial divisibility. For example, if you have $P(n)=n^2(n+1)^2Q(n)$, you can always give $Q$ an extra factor of $4$ so $P(n)=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} (4Q(n))$.

Comment: @X-Rui I am  not good at english and I can barely write english what i meant by the question is: the term $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 $ is in the partial sum of even $i$ ans $n^2(n+1)^2$  is in the partial sum of odd $i>3$ but i can't say that in a good way .

I would like to hear suggestions from you about the titlee and how to rephrase the question better

Comment: No worries! English was not really what I was trying to talk about. I was saying we don't care much about constant factors when talking about polynomial factorizations. However, maybe you indeed can propose a strong statement, that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^i= \frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}\times \frac{P_{i-2}'(n)}{N_i}$ such that $\gcd(6, a_0', a_1', a_2', \dots, a_{i-2}') = 1$, where $a_j'$'s are the coefficients of $P_{i-2}'$.

Comment: As @SamHopkins commented in the cross-post on MathOverflow, the paper [arxiv.org/abs/1705.03857](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03857) completely answers the remaining part of your question as it gives you the formula for the denominator.

Comment: Just note that the linked paper is one of those refered in [A064538](https://oeis.org/A064538) which I recommended you to check in the linked post (now deleted)

Comment: @Sil I am sorry I didn't realise that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first part of the question  was answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444681/maybe-faulhaber-polynomial-s-kx-0-have-only-rational-roots-0-frac12) (The answer shows that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m$ is divisible by ${n^2(n+1)^2}$ for odd $m>1$ and
$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m$ is divisible by ${n(2n+1)(n+1)}$ for even $m$)

---

Thanks to [Sam Hopkins](https://mathoverflow.net/users/25028/sam-hopkins) and [Sil](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/290240/sil) for recommending [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03857).

$S_m(n)=\frac{P_{m+1}}{d_m}$, where $P_{m+1}(n)$ is an $m+1$ polynomial with integer coefficients $\{ a_{m+1},\dots a_1,a_0 \}$ such that $\gcd \{ a_{m+1},\dots a_1,a_0 \}=1$.

*Theorem $1$* The paper proved that $ (m+1)\bigg|d_m $, let $q_m :=\frac{d_m}{m+1}$ st $q_m$ is an integer.

$$M_m :=
\begin{cases}
\frac{m+2}{2},  & \text{if $m$ is even} \\[2ex]
\frac{m+2}{3}, & \text{if $m$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

*Theorem $3$* Proves that $q_m = \prod\limits_{p\le M_m}p^{\varepsilon_p}$ for prime number $p$,

$$\varepsilon_2 :=
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $m=2^r-1$ for some $r$,} \\[2ex]
1, & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$

$$\varepsilon_p :=
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $\displaystyle p \not \bigg| (m+2)$ and $\displaystyle p \bigg| \dbinom{m+1}{(p-1)j}$ for all $j =2,3,\dots , \lfloor\frac{m}{p-1} \rfloor-1$,} \\[2ex]
1, & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$

---

### For odd $m>1$:

**If $m$ can be expressed as $2^r-1$** for some $r\in \mathbb{N}$, since $m>1$ the $r\ge 2$ so $d_m = (2^r) q_n$, So $\color{red}{4}\bigg|d_m$.

**If $m$ can't be expressed as $2^r-1$** for any $r \in \mathbb{N}$, then $ \varepsilon_2=1 $ and since $m$ is odd number $m+1$ is even, so $\color{red}{4}\bigg| d_m$.

Which implies that for all odd $m>1 $ the denominator $d_m$ is always divisble by $\color{red}4$.

---

### For even $m$:

It is clear that $\varepsilon_2=1 $.

Any positive integer $m$ can be expressed as $3a$ or $3a+1$ , or $3a+2$ for some non negative integer $a$.

**If $m$ can be expressed as $3a+1$** for some non negative integer $a$ It follows that $\varepsilon_3=1$ which implies that he denominator $d_m$ is divisble by $\color{blue}6$.

**If $m$ can be expressed as $3a+2$** for some non negative integer $a$ It follows that $3|M+1$ (There is no need to evaluate $\varepsilon_3$) which implies that he denominator $d_m$ is divisble by $\color{blue}6$.

**If $m$ can be expressed as $6a$** for some non negative integer $a$, we need to prove that $\varepsilon_3=1$ it is sufficient to find a $l \in \{2,4,6,\dots 6a-2 \}$ such that $3\not |\dbinom{6a+1}{l}$.
Since $6a+1 $ is odd then we can choose $l$ form $\{2,3,4,5,\dots,6a-2 \}$. Choose the largest $b\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $3^b|6a $,let $l= 3^b$.  It is clear that $$3\not\bigg|\dbinom{6a+1}{3^b} $$.

Which implies that he denominator $d_m$ is divisble by $\color{blue}6$ for all even $m$.

---

### **Remark**

For odd $p$:

$\varepsilon_p=0$ only when $m+1$ is a power of $p$ see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4835643/conjecture-binomnk-mod-m-0-for-all-k-1-2-3-dots-n-1-only-when-m)  for proof.

Answer (score 7):

Not an answer but an observation. We can rewrite these sums as follows:

$S_4 = {\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^4=\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}} \times \frac{3n^2+3n-1}{  5} = \frac{6}{5} \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2\right)\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\right) - \frac{1}{5}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2\right)$

$S_5 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^5 = \frac{4}{3} \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\right)^3  - \frac{1}{3}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^3\right)$

$S_6 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^6= \frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6} \times \frac{3n^4+6n^3-3n+1}{ 7 } = \frac{12}{7} \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2\right)\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^3\right)  - \frac{5}{7}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^4\right)$

$S_7 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^7= \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} \times\frac{3n^4+6n^3-n^2-4n+2}{ 6} = 2\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\right)^4  - \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^5\right)$

and so on.

Comment: Nice idea. As far as odd indices, generally we have simply $$ 2^{m-1} S_1^m = \sum_{j>0} \binom{m}{2j-1} S_{2m-2j+1}.$$ For even indices, it appears that $S_{k-1}S_k$ is a (rational) linear combination of $S_{2k},S_{2k-2},...,S_k$ (that is, of $S_{2k},S_{2k-2},...,S_{k+1}$ for $k$ odd). But the coefficients are much less straightforward here.

Comment: For even indices, in fact Bernoulli numbers are involved. Written most economically: $$m(m+1)(S_mS_{m-1}-B_mS_m)=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{m-1}2\rfloor}B_{2j}\binom{m+1}{2j}(2m-2j+1)S_{2m-2j}$$
Note that for odd $m$, the term with $B_m$ on the LHS vanishes.

Answer (score 5):

Two notes, 1) neither of the terms *divide* the explicit formula, as you are left with a fraction that is not guaranteed to be an integer 2) when $i=4$, it should be $$\sum_{k=0}^n k^i = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{6\cdot 5}$$ As $+1$ gives you a little bit over. Now, you want a pattern to appear, meaning you want to solve for $a_i$ ( I am only going to do when i is even) if $$\sum_{k=0}^n k^{2i} = a_i \sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \\
\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n k^{2i}}{ \sum_{k=0}^n k^2} = a_i \\$$
Thus, for our arbitary $a_i$, we can now calculate our sum. Using [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula):
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^i = \frac{1}{i+1} \sum_{k=0}^i {i + 1 \choose k} B_k n^{i+1-k} $$bernoulli number. Then, our final equation can become:

$$a_i = \frac{3}{2i+1}\frac{ \sum_{k=0}^i {i + 1 \choose k} B_k n^{i+1-k}}{ \sum_{k=0}^2 {3 \choose k} B_k n^{3-k}}$$

This may be something, it may not. The way you achieved these explicity formulas is likely very important, as you could be arbitrarily introducing the $i=2$ term and thus $a_i$ is some pseudo-random number. At the same time, it may something very interesting. Either way, if you wanted to find a non-arbitrary pattern between these, you would want to find the value of $a_i$ in explicit terms, however as $a_i$ is non-linear by a long-shot, this is likely impossible. Hence, the reason the $i=2$ term shows up constantly is probably just how you've defined it. But, if you are still hopeful there is a chance! Good luck.

Also the first terms (simplified in terms of the $i=1$ term) are:
$$\begin{align}
a_0 &= 1 \\
 a_1 &= \frac{6 \sum_{k=0}^n k-1}{5} \\ a_2 &= \frac{(6 \sum_{k=0}^n k)(n^2+n-1) - 1}{7} \end{align}$$
Which is intriguing especially since $x^2 + x -1$ is the polynomial used to derive Binet's formula for the exact value of any fibonacci number.