# Show that $\sum_{2}^{n} (k^2-k)=\frac{n^3-n}{3}$

Tags: matrices, summation, gaussian-elimination

I am reading about Gaussian elimination, and the book gives the equation for the number of multiplications/divisions needed to solve a nXn matrix
$$\sum_{2}^{n} (k^2-k)$$

The formula I can understand, but what confuses me is when the book says this:

"Through induction you can show that $$\sum_{2}^{n} (k^2-k)=\frac{n^3-n}{3}$$

Edit: Sorry, I was asking the wrong question. I can se that through induction it is true, but how did they come to $\frac{n^3-n}{3}$ without induction in the first place?

Comment: Induction. Base: $n=2 \Rightarrow 4-2=2=\frac{8-2}{3}$. Step. $n=m+1$, $S_{n}=S_{n-1}+n^2-n=\frac{m^3-m}{3}+(m+1)^2-(m+1)=\frac{m^3-m+3m^2+6m+3-3m-3}{3}=\frac{m^3+3m^2+3m+1-m-1}{3}=\frac{(m+1)^3-(m+1)}{3}$.

Comment: Do yo know what induction means ? If yes, apply it.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking the wrong question. How did they come to $\frac{n^3-n}{3}$ without induction in the first place?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu: you complicate things by introducing $m$. Simply write $S_n-S_{n-1}=\frac{n^3-n-(n-1)^3+(n-1)}3=n^2-n$.

Comment: I believe it is necessary to introduce $m$ for correct proof, $n$ is dumb number in formula to prove,$m$ is certain number in a proof.

Comment: I don't think they got to $\dfrac{n^3-n}3$ without induction in the first place.  I think they used induction to arrive at it.  What makes you think they arrived at $\dfrac{n^3-n}3$ *without* induction when the quoted text says they got there *with induction*?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu: I mean $m+1$ instead of $m$. (And $n$ makes no difference.)

Comment: I agree that induction proves the formula, but to get to do the induction you must first have an inkling of what the formula is going to be. How did they arrive at that is my question.

Comment: One way is to use binomial coefficients. $k(k-1)=2\binom k2$. If you stare at the Pascal triangle for a little while you will see why
$$\binom 22 +\binom 32=\binom 33+\binom32=\binom 43$$
hence
$$\binom 22+\binom 32+\binom42=\binom 43+\binom 42=\binom53$$
hence
$$\binom22+\binom32+\binom42+\binom52=\binom53+\binom52=\binom63$$
et cetera. Look up [hockey stick identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1490794/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This looks promising :). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any polynomial $P$ of degree $d+1$, $P(n)-P(n-1)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$. And if $P(n)$ is a sum up to $n$, then $P(n)-P(n-1)$ is the last term of the sum.

There are several ways to discover $P$. For instance by indeterminate coefficients.

With
$$\sum_{k=2}^n(k^2-k)=an^3+bn^2+cn+d,$$

you solve

$$n^2-n=a(n^3-(n-1)^3)+b(n^2-(n-1)^2)+c(n-(n-1)).$$

Also see https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/792255/Faulhaber-made-easy, which can be adapted to any polynomial function.

Comment: How can you assume that the formula is going to be a third degree polynomial?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am going to brood over it a bit.

Comment: @ErikEriksson: because $3=2+1$.

Comment: ah yes I see your point :). I will read the link you sent. Than you again.

Answer (score 1):

HINT...They have used the formulas $$\sum_{r=1}^n r^2=\frac n6(n+1)(2n+1)$$ and $$\sum_{r=1}^n r=\frac n2(n+1)$$

Comment: Thank you. The second one is easy enough, but I'm going to have to stare sum of squares a bit longer.

Comment: @ErikEriksson Many approaches to deriving that identity are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3369847/11619). A popular one uses (essentially) the hockey stick identity. Because identities of this type can be seen as telescoping sums, I tried to explain how one finds the right telescoping function by integrating the one related to the previous exponent.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I breezed past binomial equation in calculus and thought I understood it enough. But clearly there is a word there worth diving into. Thank you, this is very helpful and interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your mean is how to calculate $\sum_{k=2}^n k^2$ right?, I assume that you know $\sum_{k=2}^n k$. First Let us :
$$
S = \sum_{k=2}^n k^2 \\
P(n,k) = \sum_{i=2}^k i = \frac{(n+k)(n-k+1)}{2} = \frac{n^2 -k^2 + n +k}{2} \\
\text{especially: } P = \sum_{k=2}^n k
$$

Now we expand $\sum_{k=2}^n k^2$,
$$
\begin{align*}
S=\sum_{k=2}^n k^2 &=  2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 \cdots + n^2 \\
                 &= 2(2 + 3 +4 \cdots +n) + (3+2\cdot4+3\cdot5+\cdots+(n-2)\cdot n)\\
                 &=2(2 + 3 +4 \cdots +n) + (3 + 4 + \cdots + n) + \cdots + ((n-1) + n) + n \\
                 &=2P(n,2) + P(n,3) + P(n,4) + \cdots + P(n,n) \\
                 &\text{Using }P(n,k) \text{ 's formula, we have:} \\
                 &= P + \frac{(n-1)n}{2}+\frac{2+ \cdots +n}{2} + \frac{n^2(n-1)}{2} - \frac{S}{2} \\
                 &= \frac{3}{2}P + \frac{n^3-n}{2} - \frac{S}{2}
\end{align*}
$$

$\implies$
$$
\frac{3}{2}(S-P) = \frac{n^3-n}{n} \\
S-P = \frac{n^3-n}{3} \\
\sum_{k=2}^n(k^2-k)=S-P=\frac{n^3-n}{3} 
$$
done.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{k = 2}^n (k-1)k 
& =2\times\sum_{k = 2}^n \frac {k!}{(k-2)!\times2!}\\
& = 2\times \sum_{k = 2}^n \binom{k}{2}\\
&= 2\times\binom{n+1}{3} = \frac {n^3-n}{3}\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: you need to edit a couple of typos here - in the fraction on RHS you need $(k-2)$ not $(k-1)$